# UITabViewController includes UINavigationController

Tags: iphone

I have an app which is a UITabViewController in root, include 2 UIViewControllers and 1 UIavigationController. The UINavigationController includes another UIViewController (the third).

The app works well on iPhone.

When I migrate it to iPad, when I set the breakpoint on viewDidLoad of the third UIViewController, I found that it was not being triggered.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have created a new nib for use on the iPad.  Either you haven't hooked up all of the outlets in the iPad nib, or you haven't set the custom class correctly for that “third” view controller (or some related view controller in the nib).